# Возможно ли отследить, когда пользователь удаляет или блокирует телеграм-бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegraf

При запуске бота сохраняется `chat_id` пользователя в БД.

Есть ли способ отследить, когда пользователь удаляет или блокирует бота?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент есть только один способ, это отправка сообщения пользователю. Если он заблокировал бота, то вам выдаст ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо большое)